# why sculpt not visible in render or preview mode

Tags: sculpting

I have sculpted little and in solid view i can see what i have sculpted.

[image]

[image: u]

In preview or render view i cant see the detail or sculpt done on mesh

[image]

May i know the reason why i cannot see it. Any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details are there, but they don't show well in rendered view, because you are using

- an inconvenient lighting setup (a hdri which doesn't produce much contrast)
- a inconvenient shading setup (a fully subsurface scattering shader won't show surface normal details well).

You can use (from left to right)

- a diffuse BSDF with manually positioned lights
- a diffuse BSDF with a detailed, high contrast hdri
- a different shader which shows the face normals better.

[image: examples]